# Узнать или выставить значение уровня зума WebView

Tags: android, java, webview

Задача: есть некий документ открытый в `WebView`, но на разных экранах этот "документ" - по разному выглядит - у кого-то он не влезает в экран, у кого-то наоборот.

И нужно сделать так, чтобы пользователь один раз выставил зум, а потом это значения для зума уже загружалось бы с `SharedPreferences` (предварительно записав их).

Есть-ли какие-то методы/функции?
В документации не нашёл.

Comment: Что именно не нашли? Как сохранить/считать какие-то данные их SharedPreferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int scale = 100 * webView.getScale();
```

что бы восстановить

```
webView.setInitialScale( scale );
```